# Horizontal scrolling - Add class to active div currently in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this script to be able to scroll a section horizontally.

https://codepen.io/ellisclicky/pen/vvwRKN

```
$horizontalScrollSections.each(function (i, el) {

    var $thisSection = $(this);

    $(this).data('elDom', $(this).get(0));

    // Set up horizontal scrolling data attributes and show section all have been computed.
    setUpHorizontalScroll($(this));

    // Now we're ready, call setScene on load that adds classes based on scroll position.
    setScene($(this));

    // Resize function
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        // Reset horizontal scrolling data attributes and transform content wrapper if transform is bigger than scroll width.
        resetHorizontalScroll($thisSection);
        // Reset scene positioning.
        setScene($thisSection);
    });
```

I've truncated the code above a tad bit. Working example on the codepen.io link above.

I want to add a class to the div (named *horizontal-scroll-section__content-section* in this example) currently in viewport.

How would one go about to do that?

Super grateful for any answers.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: I'm a noob unfortunately, can you point me even more in the right direction?